# bada Programming - Close/Hide Keypad when Switch Tab

Tags: tabs, bada, keypad

May I know how to close or hide the overlay keypad from the editField when I switch tab (panel)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

Osp::Ui::IScrollPanelEventListener Interface Reference

I think you need to handle OnOtherControlSelected()

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! Do I implement this over all the panels? Or just the tabForm itself?

Comment: if you editfield is child of scrollpanel then call __pEditField->AddScrollPanelEventListener(*this). From documentation:

If the scroll panel is the parent of edit area or edit field, you can use the IScrollPanelEventListener::OnOtherControlSelected() event handler to be notified when another child is selected while the overlay keypad is open. This feature is particularly useful when there are multiple text input controls on the same screen, because the system automatically makes sure that the currently focused edit area or edit field remains visible.

Comment: yup all my editfields have scrollPanel->AddControl(*editField)

Comment: __pEditField->AddScrollPanelEventListener(*this);
are you getting a callback in OnOtherControlSelected(),
I think you need to close your keypad inside this function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5452/discussion-between-yogi-and-winona)